# UITableView: Removing cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Guys, i have a little issue here. Im doing a search to my UITableView. I search "iPhone", it returns to me one result. Its ok. iPhone just has one result. But when i search for iPad, that has two results, it gives me 2 results, but the first row stills displaying iphone info. The second display the iPad correct information.

When i click on search bar again to search another word, it gives me the two desired rows of ipad. But when i press the cancel button, it returns to the iPhone and iPad rows.

What im doing wrong?

Thanks

Cell and Table Methods:

```
        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            return [self.listCod count];
        }




        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"SearchResult";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                                     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) {
                cell =
                [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 200)
                  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier]
                 autorelease];


            UIColor *bkgColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchViewTableCellBackground.png"]];

            UIView* backgroundView = [ [ [ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero ] autorelease ];
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = bkgColor;
            cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;

            // Foto do produto

            UIView *teste = [[UIView alloc] init];
            teste.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 100);
            teste.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            [cell addSubview:teste];


            // Label de Marca

            UILabel *marca = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            marca.frame = CGRectMake(115, 10, 195, 25);
            marca.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            marca.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            NSString *marcaString = [self.listMarca objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            marca.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
            marca.text = marcaString;
            [cell addSubview:marca];
            [marca release];


            // Label do nome do produto

            UILabel *nome = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            nome.frame = CGRectMake(115, 30, 195, 25);
            nome.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            nome.textColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:26.0 / 255 green:177.0 / 255 blue:240.0 / 255 alpha:1.0];

            nome.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25.0];
                NSString *noemString = [self.listName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                nome.text = noemString;
            [cell addSubview:nome];
            [nome release];

            //Preco

            UILabel *preco = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            preco.frame = CGRectMake(115, 55, 195, 25);
            preco.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            preco.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];


            // Manda preco e parcela pra tratar

            [self priceFormat:[self.listPreco objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] :[self.listParcela objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


            preco.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
            preco.text = self.precoFinal;
            [cell addSubview:preco];


            //Parcela

            UILabel *parcelaLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            parcelaLabel.frame = CGRectMake(115, 73, 195, 25);
            parcelaLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            parcelaLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            parcelaLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
            parcelaLabel.text = self.parcelamentoFinal;

            [cell addSubview:parcelaLabel];

            }



            return cell;
        }
```

And the search bar methods:

```
            - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
                [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
                self.theTableView.allowsSelection = NO;
                self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
                [theTableView setRowHeight:110];
            }

            - (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
             willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
            {
                [tableView setRowHeight:[[self theTableView] rowHeight]];
                tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
                [self.tableData removeAllObjects];
                [self.theTableView reloadData];
            }

            - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
                searchBar.text=@"";

                [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
                [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
                self.theTableView.allowsSelection = YES;
                self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
            }


            - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
                return NO;
            }

            - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

                // Converte a String do campo de busca

                NSString* buscaGet =
                [searchBar.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                 NSASCIIStringEncoding];    


                // Conecta com a URL


                NSString *endereco = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost/icomm/test.php?nome=%@", buscaGet];

                // Lê o resultado

                TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:endereco]] retain];
                TBXMLElement * rootXMLElement = tbxml.rootXMLElement;


                TBXMLElement * item = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"produto" parentElement:rootXMLElement];

                listCod = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                listMarca = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                listName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                listPreco = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                listParcela = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                while (item) {


                    // Seta a id do produto

                    TBXMLElement * codigo = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"item" parentElement:item];
                    NSString * codProd = [TBXML textForElement:codigo];

                    [self.listCod addObject:codProd];


                    // Seta a marca do produto

                    TBXMLElement * marca = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"marca" parentElement:item];
                    NSString * marcaProd = [TBXML textForElement:marca];    
                    [self.listMarca addObject:marcaProd];

                    // Seta o nome do produto

                    TBXMLElement * nome = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"nome" parentElement:item];
                    NSString * nomeProd = [TBXML textForElement:nome];
                    [self.listName addObject:nomeProd];


                    // Seta o preco do produto

                    TBXMLElement * preco = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"preco" parentElement:item];
                    NSString * precoProd = [TBXML textForElement:preco];    
                    [self.listPreco addObject:precoProd];



                    // Seta o parcela do produto

                    TBXMLElement * parc = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"parcela" parentElement:item];
                    NSString * parcProd = [TBXML textForElement:parc];
                    [self.listParcela addObject:parcProd];




                    // Procura o proximo produto.

                    item = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"produto" searchFromElement:item
                            ];
                }


                NSLog(@"%@", self.listName);

                [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
                [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
                self.theTableView.allowsSelection = YES;
                self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

                //Remove tudo da table e recarrega

                [[[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

                [tableData removeAllObjects];
                [theTableView reloadData];

            }
```

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only setting your labels up inside the `if (cell == nil)` part of your code. This only gets called the first time a cell is created; after that the cell is dequeued for reuse and you don't create a new cell. If you want to dequeue your cells like that, you need to set the text (and any other property of the label that might change) outside of that if statement. In order to get references to your labels, you will need to use tags and `viewWithTag:`.

Or if you want to simplify things, don't dequeue your tableCells; though this could lead to performance issues if you have a lot of cells.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. But when i search iphone, and them ipad. The first row got duplicated. The iphone row not disappear. How can i clear my table of rows?

Comment: Check your listCod inside your while loop... see if the while loop is being called the correct amount of times. Also, you should be using self.listCod (with autorelease), not just listCod, when you alloc and initialize it. Your current implementation looks like it has a few memory leaks.

Comment: Yeah. Its currently being called correctly. I dont understang what about autorelease. I setted it here and got a crash.

Comment: By using listCod, instead of self.listCod, you are creating a new object, and setting listCod to point to that new object. When you do that, the object that listCod used to point to remains in memory, but with no pointer to access it. This is a memory leak. But as for the main problem, check exactly what self.listCod contains when it is referenced in `numberOfRowsInSection:`. Does it have the right number of elements? Are you seeing more table cells than you expect to see?

Comment: When i print the self.listCod it gives me the exactly waht i wants. The fact is that my rows doesnt goes when i research.

Comment: Anybody? Im still gaving this issue.

Comment: Could you edit with more specific details? Are you saying that numberOfRowsInSection returns the correct number of rows, but then you are seeing more rows than that in your table?

Comment: Its weird. When is search for iphone, it gives me one row. Correct. Perfect. When i search for ipad. It gives me 2 rows. Perfect. But the first row of iphone dont disappear and ipad's rows stay over the iphone row.

Comment: Are you saying that you end up with 3 rows total, instead of 2? Or that it looks like one row is containing all the stuff from both tablecells?

Comment: Check on this images whats happening. First search:http://cl.ly/5AB6. Second search: http://cl.ly/5APs. When i input some letter on search input: http://cl.ly/5AjJ

Comment: Ah ok. It looks like you are adding your label as a subview to the table cell even though it already has a label. If you updated your original posted code to move the label setup outside of the `if (cell == nil)` code, make sure that you only create and add your labels inside the if statement. The only thing you should do outside the if statement is set the text of the labels. That's why I was saying you would need to use tags to get references to the labels.

Comment: and how can i set a text for a object trough tag?

Comment: When you create the view, give it a tag. `preco.tag = 10;` Outside of the if statement, get a pointer to that view. `UIView * preco = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:10];` Then you can set the text. `preco.text = self.precoFinal`. Or, if you aren't doing a lot of scrolling, just get rid of the dequeuing altogether and start with a brand new table cell every time.

Comment: Yes!! Perfect! That was it! Thanks a lot man, an sorry to take to long to describe to you.